# How to render multiple .ejs files in nested form in Node.js and Express?

Tags: node.js, express, rendering, ejs

How can I render multiple `.ejs` files in a nested form?

So I have the following file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var ejs = require('ejs');
exports.index = function(req, res){
    if (req.method=='POST'){
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({user:'root', password:'root', database:'testdb'});
        var name = req.param('name');
        connection.query('select * from table_name where name = ?', name, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.render('index', {
                 title: 'title', content: res.render('index2', {data:rows})
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Where `index.ejs` consists of very basic html tag (say html, head, body, and one `p` tag) and have `<%- content %>` in it, where content is assumed to be rendered by another .ejs file, which doesn't include html, head, or body tag and is only assumed to be rendered a content and a title. However, when I accessed to this file by POST request and tried to render files and then checked out the outputted HTML file from my browser, the content consisted only of `index2.ejs` file, which means it has no html, body, head tag.

So what am I missing? And if I want to include a Javascript library by `<script src='some_file.js'></script>`, should I add another rendering property when I try to render in `index2.ejs` file...right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, I think you are confused on how `res.render` operates. According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render):

> res.render(view, [locals], callback)
>
> Render a view with a callback responding with the rendered string.

which explains why you are only seeing the content of index2.ejs in your HTML page.

---

Now, there are multiple ways to achieve your goal, which is nesting views within views. Starting from Express 3.x, you need to use `include`.In this case, you can rewrite your views like this:
1- Define a header.ejs file, which would look like this [example](https://github.com/anas-ambri/HammerTime/blob/master/src/views/header.ejs).
2- Define a footer.ejs. which would look like this other [example](https://github.com/anas-ambri/HammerTime/blob/master/src/views/footer.ejs).
3- In your index2.ejs, include these two files, like this:

```
<% include header %>
    //The HTML of your index2.ejs
    //You can add some reusable views, like, say, a submit button above the footer
    <% include reusable_views/submit %>
<% include footer %>
```

A second method is to use [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals), which allows you to insert any view by only specifying their path:

```
res.render('index', {
                 title: 'title', 
                 content: 'index2', 
                 data:rows
            });
```

And, in your index1.ejs, you will have:

```
<html><head>
<title><%= title %></title></head>
<body><p>
<%- partial('index2',{}) %>
</p></body></html>
```

The advantage of this method is you can pass extra values to your view, using the extra object. Check out the ejs-locals github page for more details.

Comment: ejs-locals looks great! It's weird that a 3rd party module like that is needed for what is supposed to be a templating system O.o

Comment: Welcome to node. It's all 3rd party modules all the way down

Comment: Sure, but I would expect _express_ to handle that on its own. How do you write a templating system that doesn't enable you to simply insert building blocks?

Answer (score 4):

Update : ejs-mate Express 4.x locals for layout, partial.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-mate

cf https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application