# In Sails js how to load alternative templates within the front page (all screens)

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, sails.js

In Sails js we design a main template where our app replaces (in turn, on click) nested templates within, in place of the initial nested app template.

We may not use any library or framework on top of Sails, unless necessary.

The question is : **in Sails** js what is the most efficient way to display **alternative templates** within the *front page* template ?

**Do header and footer combined with ejs-locals run/render well on smartphones ?**

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: ejs by default in Sails

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render multiple .ejs files in nested form in Node.js and Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014384/how-to-render-multiple-ejs-files-in-nested-form-in-node-js-and-express)

Comment: Another resource for you that you can try is the Sails Gitter chatroom. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: maybe you can adding this template in assets  folder..